# Android Material Design Theme picker color

Tags: android, picker

I have a Material design theme in Android. I want to change my picker label and button color because it appear in white color (colorPrimary) but I can't do it.

This is my theme:

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Cuponisimo" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/azulCuponisimo</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/azulOscuro</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/azulCuponisimo</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/azulClaro</item>

        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/azulCuponisimo</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/azulCuponisimo</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>

    </style>

    <color name="azulCuponisimo">#0a80b0</color>
    <color name="azulOscuro">#01506e</color>
    <color name="azulClaro">#9dccdf</color>

</resources>
```

[image]

I want that my picker have azulCuponisimo color, but always is white. Please help me!

Comment: try to change text color in your `list_item` for your spinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution:

In android-holo-colors create the ColorSpinner and then,

**custom_theme.xml**

```
<item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/Spinner</item>
<item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>
<item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
```

**styles_nameTheme.xml**

```
<style name="Spinner" parent="android:Widget.Spinner">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/nameTheme_spinner_background_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/nameTheme_list_selector_holo_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SpinnerDropDownItem" parent="android:Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner">
        <item name="android:checkMark">@drawable/nameTheme_btn_radio_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/verdeOscuro</item>
        <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SpinnerItem" parent="android:Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/AppearanceSpinnerItem</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppearanceSpinnerItem" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/verdeOscuro</item>
    </style>
```

That's work perfectly. I hope it can help you.